# Convert grid with multiple pages to pdf

Tags: c#, export-to-pdf

Im having an error when converting grid with multiple pages to pdf,

```
RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();

Source Error:


Line 465:
Line 466:
Line 467:        GridDistrictWise.RenderControl(hw);
Line 468:
Line 469:        GridDistrictWise.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
```

There is no error when i try to export single page of grid.This is my code,

```cs
 protected void btn_Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ExportGridToPDF();

        // btnPrintAllPages_Click();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=License_Details.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);


        GridDistrictWise.RenderControl(hw);

        GridDistrictWise.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
        GridDistrictWise.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
        GridDistrictWise.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
        GridDistrictWise.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
        GridDistrictWise.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
        GridDistrictWise.AllowPaging = false;
        GridDistrictWise.DataBind();


        // ExportToPDF(GridDistrictWise, true);
    }

   public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }
```

is there any other way to export grid with lots of pages to pdf? Data table to pdf?
Help me out guys

Answer (score 0):

You should create pdf file (or stream) on sever side and send it as pdf stream. You can't do html and say that it's pdf.